# Python question on Use of np.select on Dataframe to extract date range over certain consecutive changes occur

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe df containing following columns for say Ticker SPY over say 10 years at daily frequency. The columns are:

1. Date
2. Close Price
3. PCT change

How do I write np.select query to find out time-period (Start-end Dates) over which each-day price went up by min x%, each day upto n-consequetive days?

I do not know how to solve this issue. I wrote np.select to discern patterns Ux for UUU..x times by min x%, where U: % Change is Up. But I hav no clue to extrcting data range over which this occurred.

Comment: Provide your data and current code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.